# How to Pass User's Email Address from NHibernate and Windsor to MVC3 View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, castle-windsor

I'm working on a NHibernate, Castle Windsor and MVC3 project.  I need to pass the view the currently logged in user's email address.  The custom membership provider is in the namespace.CustomProviders.WebWindsorMembershipProvider.  How do I pass the email address to my Razor view?

Our Custom membership provider defines usr.Email as part of this:

```
private MembershipUser GetMembershipUserFromUser(User usr)
    {
        MembershipUser u = new MembershipUser("WebWindsorMembershipProvider",
                                              usr.Username,
                                              usr.Id,
                                              usr.Email,
                                              usr.SecretQuestion,
                                              usr.SecretAnswer,
                                              usr.IsApproved,
                                              usr.IsLockedOut,
                                              (usr.CreationDate.HasValue) ? usr.CreationDate.Value : DateTime.Now,
                                              (usr.LastLoginDate.HasValue)
                                                  ? usr.LastLoginDate.Value
                                                  : Utils.MinDate(),
                                              (usr.LastActivityDate.HasValue)
                                                  ? usr.LastActivityDate.Value
                                                  : Utils.MinDate(),
                                              (usr.LastPasswordChangedDate.HasValue)
                                                  ? usr.LastPasswordChangedDate.Value
                                                  : Utils.MinDate(),
                                              (usr.LastLockedOutDate.HasValue)
                                                  ? usr.LastLockedOutDate.Value
                                                  : Utils.MinDate()); 

        return u;
    }
```

How do I pass the usr.Email value from the custom provider to embed into a H2 tag in my AccountInfo view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing of how you have implemented your membership system, but assuming it uses the standard Membership interface, then you just do this:

```
return View(Membership.GetUser().Email)
```

If you are using a view model, then you just do the same thing but add it to a view model and pass the view model to the view.

Not sure why you feel this is difficult.